# How to check if all the props sent from react native are going to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, react-native-ios

When I send some props to the WebView component from react native code I would like to know if I can check if the props reached the Objective-C side, by using a console.log alternative and check them from Objective-C. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***NSLog*** method to log your parameters in obective-c.

Comment: Yes. But what should I log ? Some object, class ? Currently the approach that I am using is the XCode debugger. But I want to see all the props in the console, like we do in react native using browser console.